# Reverse geocoding in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

> Hi I am using the below code for reverse geocoding but i am not getting accurate result, i am getting nearly 1.2km difference,Below is my code.

```
$scope.getloc=function(){
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng("47.1464936", "-122.443986");
        var geocoder = geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latlng }, function (results, status) {

            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                if (results[1]) {

                    $scope.Formatedaddress=results[1].formatted_address
                    console.log($scope.Formatedaddress)
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

> The above given coordinates or of location Pacific Lutheran University,
>   but when i am getting Parkland, WA, USA as result

Answer (score 0):

I think you get the result Parkland, WA, USA because the address Pacific Lutheran University is inside the boundaries of the address Parkland, WA, USA, if you check by using the [Google Maps](https://www.google.com.ph/maps?source=tldso) to get their coordinates.

I suggest you to use the [`Place_id`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#reverse-place-id) instead of `lat` and `lng` to be more specific in the address that you want to get.

For example, this is the `place_id` for **Pacific Lutheran University**.

> Place ID: ChIJ7f9NLYEBkVQRJ2hX6QH68Dk

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?place_id=ChIJ7f9NLYEBkVQRJ2hX6QH68Dk&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

And the `place_id` for **Parkland, WA, USA**

> Place ID: ChIJJ69eTS4CkVQRTD2nPe2Cjw0

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?place_id=ChIJJ69eTS4CkVQRTD2nPe2Cjw0&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

Now, you can check the difference of the two requests.

For more information about `place_id`, check this [link](https://developers.google.com/places/place-id).

Comment: location is not static it will change for every event.